# Notice: Array to string conversion $text = $htmlTag[0]

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am getting the notice:

> **Notice: Array to string conversion in** E:\XAMP\htdocs\1\plugins\content\cedtag\cedtag.php on line 148
>    Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\XAMP\htdocs\1\plugins\content\cedtag\cedtag.php on line 141

This is the part of the code where I'm getting the error:

```
if ($position == 1) {
        $text = $htmlTag[0] . $text;
    } else {
        if ($position == 2) {
            // Both before and after Text
            $text = $htmlTag[0] . $text . $htmlTag[0];
        } else {
            // After Text
            $text .= $htmlTag[0];
        }
    }
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: One of your values is an array. It needs to be a string...just like the error says.

Comment: What's the content of `$htmlTag[0]`? Call `var_dump($htmlTag[0]);` to get it.

Comment: Make sure $htmlTag[0] is a string not an array ultimately $htmlTag must not be a multidimensional array.

Comment: Problem Solved with this  var_dump($htmlTag[0]); Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on your variables. One of them is an Array and PHP can't convert an Array into a string.

Comment: You have pointed out the exact thing. +1